# How to show multiple table list in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to show multiple table list in mysql

i have two tables

1) Sales_media
2) Rent_media

```
1)sales_media table

ID | Property_titile | Username| city|
1  | Big House  Sale | xyz     | newyork


2) rent_media table

ID | Property_titile | Username| city|
1  | Big House Rent  | xyz     | newyork
```

i want to show two table result togetter
Like this

```
1  | Big House  Sale | xyz     | newyork
1  | Big House Rent  | xyz     | newyork
```

how can i do this 
please help me to fix this issue

thanks

here is code but it is not showing a result

SELECT * FROM  sales_media,rent_media WHERE $construct AND user_name='$row->user_name' ORDER BY city DESC, ID DESC

Comment: what is the value of `$construct` ?

Comment: is any answer seems useful then please mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the column names on both tables are same.

```
  (SELECT * FROM sales_media WHERE user_name='$row->user_name')
UNION
  (SELECT * FROM rent_media WHERE user_name='$row->user_name') 
ORDER BY city DESC, ID DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this one:

```
SELECT * FROM sales_media inner join rent_media on sales_media.username = rent_media.username ORDER BY city DESC, ID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query:

```
SELECT ID, Property_titile, Username, city FROM sales_media table
    UNION ALL
   SELECT ID, Property_titile, Username, city FROM rent_media table ORDER BY city DESC;
```